# Exclude SUM From Results if it Equals 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following data structures:

A Question Table

```
QuestionID  | Question  | Error
      1        Who?         1
      2        What?        0
      3        When?        1
      4        Who?        1
```

QuestionID is an int, Question is a varchar, and Error is a bit field.

A User Stat Table

```
   User | QuestionID  
   Mary       1
   Joe        2
   Mary       3
   Mary       1
```

User is a varchar, QuestionID is an int.

I am trying to design two queries.

In the first query I am trying to group by the questions, and say Who? has been answered wrong twice, When? answered wrong once, and NOT report on anything for what? because it had no wrong answers. This is what I have so far, everything is working but I am having difficulty not including the What? question in the results, currently it returns "0" and is included in the results:

```
SELECT 'Question - ' +[Question] + ' - Answered Wrong ' + 
CAST(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Error)) as varchar) + 'Times' As Report
FROM [Questions]
GROUP BY [Question];
```

In my second query, I am trying to relate the tables via the QuestionID column. Essentially, trying to say Mary answered QuestionID 1 wrong twice, and QuestionID 3 wrong once. I don't have anything yet for that query. The full string expected from this query would be similiar to:

```
"Mary Answered Question Who? Wrong 2 Times"
"Mary Answered Question When? Wrong 1 Times"
```

And nothing for Joe, because he didn't answer anything wrong.

SQL Server 2012, I can't control the data structure. TIA!

Comment: You need to add a WHERE clause .. `FROM [Questions]  WHERE Error > 0
GROUP BY [Question];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `having` clause to filter the result after grouping. Add this last in the query:

```
HAVING SUM(CONVERT(INT, Error)) > 0
```

For the second query you would join the tables and group on the user:

```
SELECT [User] + ' answered question ' + [Question] + ' wrong ' + 
CAST(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Error)) as varchar) + ' times' As Report
FROM [Questions] q
INNER JOIN [User Stat] u on u.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
GROUP BY [User]
HAVING SUM(CONVERT(INT, Error)) > 0
```

Comment: This definitely works, but what would the second query look like?

Comment: @user3010406: Sorry, missed that. I added code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `HAVING` clause to state the `SUM` must be larger than 0 would make sense.

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function in a `where` clause.